# Periodicity and period of a real function satisfying $f(x+a)=\frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{f(x)-f(x)^2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

The question is:

> Let $f(x)$ be a real valued function defined for all real numbers $x$ such that for for some fixed real number $a>0$, $f(x+a)=\frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{f(x)-f(x)^2}$ and $\frac12\le f(x) \le 1$ for all $x$. Show that $f(x)$ is periodic with period $2a$.

I tried to do this by replacing $x-a$ by $x$ and then writing this equation where $p$ is the period,
$$ f(x-a+p)-f(x-a+p)^2=f(x-a)-f(x-a)^2 $$
but this leads nowhere. Can anybody explain to me how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It is quite straightforward

$$f(x+2a)=\frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{f(x+a)-(f(x+a))^2}=\frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{(f(x)-\frac{1}{2})^2 }=f(x)$$
where I used the Hypothesis $\frac12\le f(x) $ for all $x$